# How can I iterate over syscalls (as returned with `axt`) and rewrite them?

Tags: radare2

Let's say I want to list all calls that issue kill,

```
axt @ sym.imp.kill
```

How can I now NOP out the `syscall` at **all** of the addresses given? I want to strip the program of calls to kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get that working with `@@=axt sym.imp.kill`,

```
wao nop @@=`axt sym.imp.kill`
```